# setup mysql for JWTAuth::attempt() in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, rest, laravel, jwt

im newbie to laravel and just started to setup rest API . Everything is working fine but i want to implement jwtAuth base token authentication . i followed [this](http://blog.nedex.io/create-an-api-server-for-mobile-apps-using-laravel-5-1/) tutorial to setup jwtAuth and its working fine but JWTAuth::attempt() using default database and i want to use mysql and its already setup in database.php but still its not working with mysql.

these are the sample codes im using :

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'db',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

route is setup like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
Route::post('login', 'Api\AuthController@login');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh']], function() {
    Route::post('logout', 'Api\AuthController@logout');
    Route::get('test', function(){
        return response()->json(['foo'=>'bar']);
    });
});
```

});

AuthController is setup like this

```
class AuthController extends Controller {

public function login(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->only('customers_email_address', 'customers_password');        
    try {           
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {           
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }      
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```